# Unable to save associated (hasOne) data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am creating a simple API with CakePHP 4, and I am having some issues saving some POST data. This is a new project, so the models are newly baked, based on my 3 tables: `elaborations`, `details`, `jobs`

The `ElaborationTable` table has these relations:

```
$this->hasOne('Details', [ // this (and the next) is the only thing that I've manually  changed here: hasOne instead of hasMany
    'foreignKey' => 'elaboration_id',
]);
$this->hasOne('Jobs', [
    'foreignKey' => 'elaboration_id',
]);
```

While both `DetailsTable` and `JobsTable` have this:

```
$this->belongsTo('Elaborations', [
    'foreignKey' => 'elaboration_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER',
]);
```

In my controller, this is what I'm using to retrieve the POST data and save it to each database table:

```
$data = $this->request->getData();
$data['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');

$elaboration = $this->Elaborations->newEntity($data, [
    'associated' => [
        'Details',
        'Jobs'
    ]
]);
```

Finally, my POST data is something like this:

```
APP/Controller/ElaborationsController.php (line 85)
[
    'detail' => [
        'regione' => 'Lazio',
        'provincia' => 'RM',
        'comune' => 'Roma',
    ],
    'job' => [
        'serramenti' => '1',
    ],
    'user_id' => (int) 2,
]
```

Now, the `user_id` field gets saved in my `elaborations` table, no errors are issued, but still the `details` and `jobs` tables remains empty, no data is saved.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are `detail` and `job` accessible in your Elaboration entity?

Comment: Dang you've made me see the issue. Those values where accessible, but in its plural form `details` and `jobs`. That's because the bake command wrote it that way... I've set it to `detail` and `job` and it works now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: FYI, bake cannot distinguish between `hasOne` and `hasMany`, as in both cases the foreign key is in the target table, and the location of the foreign key is the only hint to figure out the type of association. Because of that bake will only try to detect `hasMany`, and that way you end up with plural names.

Comment: I guess maybe bake could check for a unique index on the foreign key, if one is present, then it could be assumed that it should be a `hasOne` association.

Comment: @ndm automating it using the unique index would be nice, but in my opinion it's not a big deal, it's my bad that I've missed it... maybe adding a simple comment explaining what to change for `hasOne` associations would be enough even for inattentive people -like I was today-